# Can we read built-in counters in Hadoop for individual tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins, hadoop-partitioning

1. Can we read built-in counters in Hadoop for individual tasks and in a periodic manner (say every 500 ms or 1 sec) and record in a file. If we can do that then how to do that?
2. How to get the individual task pids?